# WSL fix ip fail in win 11 by C# command after reboot pc

Tags: c#, powershell, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My wsl config content

---

[wsl2]
memory=4GB
kernel = C:\MySystem\kernel
swap = 8GB
networkingMode = bridged
vmSwitch = WSL
ipv6 = true
macAddress = 00:15:5d:0b:1f:3e

---

when i reboot my pc , and execute powershell command by c# program.

command list:

---

wsl -d mySystem --shutdown

Remove-VMSwitch -Name 'WSL' -Force

New-VMSwitch -Name 'WSL' -SwitchType internal

Set-VMSwitch WSL -NetAdapterName "Ethernet"

wsl -d mySystem --start

---

Set VMSwitch get error message: ObjectNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMSwitch

but if i execute those commands by powershell command line window , result is correct.

if i execute my c# program first , than run same command in powershell command line window.

I will get same error message in powershell command line window.

this is my c# code for execute powershell command:

```
private List<String> PowershellCmd(String argument, System.Text.Encoding type, bool waitExit =      true, int timeoutMs = 0)
{
  
     List<String> resultList = new List<String>();
  
     Process process = new Process();
    
     process.StartInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/c \"{0}\"", argument);
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = waitExit;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = waitExit;
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    
     if (waitExit)
         process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = type;
    
     process.Start();
    
     bool waitForExitResult = false;
     if (waitExit)
     {
         waitForExitResult = process.WaitForExit(timeoutMs <= 0 ? 60000 : timeoutMs);
         if (waitForExitResult == false)
         {
             resultList.Add("timeout_process");
         }
     }
    
     if (waitExit && waitForExitResult)
     {
         String result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
         resultList.Add(result);
         string errorResponse = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
         resultList.Add(errorResponse);
     }
    
     return resultList;
 }
```

I have used  System.Management.Automation library , but still get same error.

Dose anyone know why Set-VMSwitch fail?